# VSTS Deploy Service Fabric Application Task: Compress Package setting failing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We're attempting to set up a CI/CD build/release which includes a service fabric application. Unfortunately I've hit a stumbling block. I have the Compress Package option selected in Advanced Settings for the task but when the hosted release agent runs I get the following message:

`##[warning]The CompressPackage parameter requires version '2.5' of the Service Fabric SDK, but the installed version is '2.4.164.9494'. This parameter will be ignored.`

What am I missing here? This is the SDK that's installed on the hosted agent which AFAIK I have no control over. Why would the option be available if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

According to the warning message, you are running the build with [Hosted Agent](https://github.com/adventworks/hosted-pool-images/blob/2017.10.02/vs2015-on-windows-2012r2/image.md) which has Service Fabric SDK 2.4.164 installed.

To fix this issue, you can run the build with [Hosted 2017 Agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) which has SDK Version: 3.2.162.9494 installed. Or you can also configure [Private Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#install) if Hosted 2017 Agent does not meet your requirement.